# Is it possible to write Sync blocking IO in pure Javascript (nodejs) without c code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. Is Javascript by design discourages  or does not allow Sync blocking IO ?
2. Why is there no sleep API in Javascript ? Is it due to above point?
3. Can Browsers have more than single thread executing javascript ? Why is it always single thread?

Does the above points (due to browser restrictions) make javascript ideal language for server side non-blocking language?

Answer (score 0):

Browser will only ever run Javascript in one thread (at least per domain, and except for Web Workers).
This is primarily for simplicity; until recently, no-one wrote a threading API for Javascript.

To make the browsers simpler to write (and faster), this thread is the browser UI thread.  Therefore, any synchronous work (or a sleep call) in Javascript will freeze the browser.
This is why synchronous operations are heavily discouraged.

Comment: @josh3736: That's not necessarily true.  If you call `window.open()`, the new window must share your UI thread.

Comment: [That's true](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/V2FTT/), but only because JS allows the opening window to retain a reference to the internals of the opened window (and therefore, must share a thread).  **It does not matter what domain the opened page is on.**  Also, if you open two copies of the fiddle in two windows and block in one, the other is unaffected (even though they're on the same domain).